# Deep Overlap merge into deleted file in Accurev

Tags: merge, accurev

Using Accurev, I have some deeply overlapped files to merge into my stream although in the stream the files are defunct.  I don't want the files from the merge I just want to get rid of the overlaps and make sure that the files keep their defunct status.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get around this by promoting the missing file to the stream, resolving the merge, and then defuncting it again afterwards.

Comment: Yes I think this was my bodge of choice.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the merge, once complete, just defunct the file and promote.